# How can I solve for t if is part of $2 = {A+Bt \over A-Bt}?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $2 = {A+Bt \over A-Bt}$

I've tried cross multiplying and have come up with a possible solution but I have no one to verify for me as it is very late where I am.

$$2(A-Bt) = A+Bt\\
2A-2Bt = A+Bt\\
A = 3Bt\\
{A \over 3B} = t$$

Is this the answer?

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting tips.

Comment: Looks good to me! Do note that $B$ should not be zero nor should $A$ be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Your working seems fine.

If you substitute it back in and check:
$$\frac{A+Bt}{A-Bt}=\frac{A+\frac{A}3}{A-\frac{A}3}=\frac{4A}{2A}=2$$